# In a UWP app how to prevent the Gamepad to move the caret too?

Tags: uwp, mvvm-light, gamepad

In a UWP application I need input from the Gamepad. It works fine, but I also get the unwanted side effect that the current caret moves through the app as the user moves the thumbstick. How to prevent the caret from moving?

The app is mainly based on MVVM with MVVM light, but the Gamepad is handled in the code behind of the view.

Here is the view constructor in the code behind (the view is called `Settings` and derived from `Page`).

```cs
public Settings()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Gamecontroller
    gameControllerUpdateTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    gameControllerUpdateTimer.Tick += gameControllerUpdateTimer_Callback;
    gameControllerUpdateTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);

    GameControllerConnected = false;
    Gamepad.GamepadAdded += Gamepad_GamepadAdded;
    Gamepad.GamepadRemoved += Gamepad_GamepadRemoved;
}
```

and the three event handlers: two for Gamepad detection and removal, and one for reading the Gamepad inputs.

```cs
// Called periodically to check for user input throught the gamepad
void gameControllerUpdateTimer_Callback(object sender, object e)
{
    if (GameControllerConnected)
    {
        Gamepad gamePad = Gamepad.Gamepads[0];
        GamepadReading readings = gamePad.GetCurrentReading();
        LeftThumbStickX = readings.LeftThumbstickX;
        LeftThumbStickY = readings.LeftThumbstickY;
    }
}

// Called upon gamepad detection
async void Gamepad_GamepadAdded(object sender, Gamepad e)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(
            CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                GameControllerConnected = true;
                gameControllerUpdateTimer.Start();
            });

}

// Called upon gamepad removal
async void Gamepad_GamepadRemoved(object sender, Gamepad e)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(
            CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                GameControllerConnected = false;
                gameControllerUpdateTimer.Stop();
            });
}
```

**EDIT**: Below there's a screenshot of the app I'm working on. The caret/cursor is in one of the `Textbox`. When I move the left thumbstick on the `Gamepad`, the caret/cursor moves too: it moves from one `Textbox` to the other, or maybe better saying it causes the app to change the currently focused UI Control.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean current caret? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: @MartinZikmund thank you for your interest. I've just uploaded a screenshot hopefully to better explain the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the `KeyDown` event on the top `UIElement` in your view?

```cs
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.GamepadLeftThumbstickLeft ||
       e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.GamepadLeftThumbstickRight ||
       e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.GamepadLeftThumbstickDown ||
       e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.GamepadLeftThumbstickUp)
    {
        // do something or... nothing
        e.Handled == true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, I will try it and report.

Comment: Ok, it worked| Thanks a lot! I edited your answer with the actual code I used

Comment: somethimes the CoreWindow and/or PreviewKey…-Methods are even better for this.